# Cannot Modify GC in Xlib after call to XClearArea

Tags: c, linux, xlib, motif

Here is my problem:

I use the `XClearArea` to clear an area of the screen with the Window background pixmap. This has the foreground color as BLACK for the Graphic Context.

Following the call to `XClearArea` I try to draw a line using the `XDrawLine` API. Here I use a GC which has the foreground RED.

However, I notice that the call to `XDrawLine` draws a Black Line. In other words, `XClearArea` does not allow me to turn the Foreground to RED , inspite of explicitly specifiying the new GC in my call to `XDrawLine`.

Could anyone please throw some light on why this happens and how this problem can be fixed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Let me add some CODE to show my problem. I am trying to implement a line on the drawing area that can be moved using the arrow keys on the keyboard. Here's what I am trying to do:

- Draw a line.
- Click on the line to make it RED.
- Use the arrow key to move the line to the left or the right.
- When the arrow key is used, the line still stays RED.

When the arrow key is used, I try to clear the previous line using the `XClearArea` API,

```
XClearArea(XtDisplay(Widget,XtWindow(Widget),0, 0,WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, True);
```

The background PIXMAP has foreground black.

Now once this is done, trying to draw a line using the `XDrawLine` function:

```
XDrawLine(XtDisplay(Widget, XtWindow(Widget),RED_GC,x1, y1,x2,y2);
```

Here I am trying to use the new RED_GC that can set the foreground to RED.

However, the system still seems to draw a line with the foreground as Black.

Unfortunately I have to work with Xlib using the OpenMotif Window Manager. I cannot use GTK/QT.

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: Show more code. Did you consider using a toolkit like Gtk or Qt ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what to tell you without full code but...

XtDisplay call only accepts 1 parameter.

so

XClearArea(XtDisplay(Widget,XtWindow(Widget),0, 0,WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, True);

Should probably be:

XClearArea(XtDisplay(Widget),XtWindow(Widget),0, 0,WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, True);

Same for XDrawLine()

Also you may be better off calling

XSetForeground (XtDisplay(Widget), YourGC, YourRedpixel);

to set the foreground. (But maybe you are...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul. By calling XSetForeground, we are trying to modify the main GC. That would work, but the problem is why cant we use a new RED_GC in the call to XDrawLine instead of having to modify the foreground of the existing GC.